# how to commit and start a new transaction within a single request?

Tags: nhibernate

I am using the repository pattern in nhibernate.
In a asp.net mvc application.
I have a httpmodule, that:

```
beginRequest it calls session.beginTransaction();
EndRequest it calls session.Transaction.Commit();
```

This is fine for 95% of the time.

I have a case where I need to do the following in a single request:

```
List<User> users = factory.getUsers();

// update users

// commit transaction

// load users from the db again
```

Should I just call:

```
factory.Session.Transaction.Commit();
factory.Session.BeginTransaction();
```

**I know this is one of the reasons against using the Repository pattern**, and having the Session start/end in a HttpModule, but anyway that is how I am doing it :)

What are my options?

**Uptate**
**So basically I will now have:**

A page request will look like:

```
BeginRequest:  Session.BeginTransaction();

userlist.aspx:   
               // code to fetch users from the db
               // update users
               Session.Transaction.Commit();
               Session.BeginTransaction();
               // code to fetch recently commited users form db

EndRequest:    Session.Transaction.Commit();
```

Does the above seem correct?

I guess I should also first check if there is a current transaction before calling commit and begin again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two pieces of logic

```
List<User> users = factory.getUsers();

// update users
```

and

```
load users
```

and you want those to be in separate transactions. So you add the appropriate Starts and Commits. It works, where's the problem?

> having the Session start/end in a
>   HttpModule, but anyway that is how I
>   am doing it :) What are my options?

Is the point of the discussion whether to have Session start end in HttpModule? Well, your options is not to do it! You have a block of logic (admitedly here very simple logic) potentially it's reusable so move it to its own class. Do you think it's better to have

client code:

```
  useSomeLogic() // bzzzt forgot to start session

  startSession()
  useSomeLogic()  // ok thank you, I can work, but please remember to commit
  commit()
```

Or

```
  useSomeLogic() // just fine, I'll start the session and do you work for you and commit
```

I like nicely packaged reusable code, and that's why I refactor things away from transport-specific modules.